# Can't use .print() for new window in mozilla firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I have Query javascript using jQuery framework, Why i can't use .print() in My Mozilla firefox?

```
var printing = window.open("","Title","width=9999,height=9999");
printing.document.write('<head></head><body></body>');
printing = $(printing.document.body);
printing.html("<h1>TEST</h1><text class='remove_print'>yeah</text>");
printing.find(".remove_print").remove();
printing.print();
```

**Edited:**
i have error : printing.print is not a function.

Comment: What happens when you try? Is there an error in the web console?

Comment: i have error : printing.print is not a function @Barmar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you overwrote the `printing` variable, so it no longer contains the window you opened, when you did:

```
printing = $(printing.document.body);
```

Solution: use a different variable.

```
var printing = window.open("","Title","width=9999,height=9999");
printing.document.write('<head></head><body></body>');
var printBody = $(printing.document.body);
printBody.html("<h1>TEST</h1><text class='remove_print'>yeah</text>");
printBody.find(".remove_print").remove();
printing.print();
```

Comment: Thanks for advance!, You'ar the best :) @Barmar